# Using Multi Touch Gestures for Desktop Shifting

Tags: release-loki, touchpad, workspace, multitasking-view

followed posts from Bulletmark and Neal Fennimore

I can't get multi touch gestures working for desktop shifting.

My process

> git clone http://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
>   cd libinput-gestures
>   sudo make install
>   sudo apt install libinput-tools xdotool
>   sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
>   libinput-gestures-setup autostart

Then

> sudo apt-get xdotool wmctrl

Then I copied the conf file

> sudo cp /etc/libinput-gestures.conf ~/.config/

The edited that file

> sudo nano ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf

Added the following on the bottom,

> gesture swipe down 3 xdotool super+Down
>   gesture swipe left 3 xdotool super+Left
>   gesture swipe right 3 xdotool super+Right

After saving the file, restarting or logging off and then logging back in I don't get any workspace changing on gesture.

My trackpad is capable, it two finger scrolls well.

When I open the keyboard map its noted that my left windows button is listed as 'Super L' and when I try to remap the workspace shifter keyboard shortcut it thinks my left windows key is Super L and displays the Mac command button icon.

This all seems good compared to what others have posted, but I can't get it to shift workspaces.

Ideally I'd want 3 fingers swiping left and right to shift workspaces left and right and then 3 fingers swipe down to open the exploded multitasking view.

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Working fine for me on Juno 5.0. Just changed key codes:

```
gesture swipe down 3 xdotool key super+Down
gesture swipe right 3 xdotool key super+Left
gesture swipe left 3 xdotool key super+Right
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just followed the instructions on https://neal.codes/blog/adding-mac-like-touch-gestures-to-elementary-os , I have tested everything except the chapter "Better tap to click" and it works perfect for me.

The only difference I found compared to the instructions you did is `libinput-gestures-setup restart` - you have `autostart`. I have tried with `start` also and it works fine, probably you have to try one of these options. Also in order to work you have to log-out>log-in after you add yourself into the input group - this was a notice I read on the shell when I have tried `libinput-gestures-setup start` before logging out.

Good luck!