# How can I disable workspace switching with 2 fingers on touchpad after installing libgesture?

Tags: touchpad, workspace, gesture

Here's my setup:

- Dell precision 5540
- elementary OS Hera (up to date as of 12/17)

In order to have a macOS like experience I installed lib gesture to switch workspace using a 3-finger gesture.

Unfortunately, it seems to have some weird 2-finger behavior that switches the workspace on a very slight horizontal 2-finger gesture; 2 fingers are to scroll a window content and not switch workspaces.

I disabled lib gesture to test if it was the culprit but no. It's seems to be managed by the OS. If I disable scrolling in **System Settings** → **Mouse & Touchpad** → **Touchpad**, this gesture is disabled. I only want to scroll window content using 2 fingers, not workspaces.

Comment: Probably you mean up-to-date Hera, because Juno do not receive any updates anymore. I have libinput gestures also, on a HP Pavilion Powerbook and everything works as it should. Can you share (edit your question and add) your ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf file?

Comment: Indeed 5.1 Hera, I apt update/upgrade very often.

If I remove comments in /libinput-gestures.conf:

```gesture swipe up    3 xdotool key super+a
gesture swipe down  3 xdotool key Escape
gesture swipe right 3 _internal ws_down
gesture swipe left  3 _internal ws_up
device all```


Anyway, I don't think that's libinput gesture because I stopped it and my 3 fingers gesture was not working as expected but the 2 fingers gesture was still there....

Comment: I wonder if it's something else, not libinput-gestures, which is managing 2-finger gestures? For me, I can't even select 2-fingers in the Gestures gui (for swiping).

Comment: My guess is that it's the OS because if f I disable in Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > Scrolling > 2 fingers, this gesture is disabled...

Comment: I am using this on Loki, Juno and now Hera with no any problems. Can you share the guide you followed in order to activate the libinput gestures?

Comment: I used this page: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14452/using-multi-touch-gestures-for-desktop-shifting

Comment: Anyway, I think there's a misunderstanding, even more when title was edited with an incorrect title... 

Lib gesture works just fine. 

I have for some reason 2 fingers by the OS or another piece of software and I don't find a way to remove it...

Comment: Hey, @damkenso. How did you solve the problem? I'm having the exact same issue and it is really frustrating.

Comment: @Arif, well I didn't... I tried to install synaptic instead but I still have the same problem... :'(

Comment: @damkenso, that is crazy... I switched to XFCE to test if problem still exists and it was fine there. Going to replace my ubuntu with something else...
Another thing is if I tap with three fingers it opens `activites`. Does it do the same thing for you?

Comment: @Arif, well, I don't know, I disabled the touchpad and using a mouse...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the physical clicking from multitouch to hardware default and you will have right click with options inside mouse and touchpad options

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

[image: libinput conf]

Please see my screenshot:
That's how I have my gestures configured in order to swipe workspaces with 4 fingers and do some minimize with three. Also three finger Back/Fwd for the browser navigation :)